# Ionic2, Microsoft package, & Azure ADAL failed Authentication

Tags: ionic2, adal

I am posting after extensive research about the subject and hope to get an answer.
I am using ADAL for Azure authentication following the Ionic2 guide: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ms-adal/

In it, they define the AuthenticationContext as follows:

```
let authContext: AuthenticationContext = this.msAdal.createAuthenticationContext('https://login.windows.net/common');
```

When I run the app in the browser, immediately i get a "validation failed: undefined" error message.

Other guides define the variable as follows:

```
var authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext('https://login.windows.net/common');
```

I couldn't import Microsoft package, so I followed the solution for this question: [3rd Party Library “cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps” not getting recognized in my Ionic 2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016964/3rd-party-library-cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps-not-getting-recognized-i)

However, now i get the error: cannot read property 'ADAL' of undefined

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MS AL a cordova plugin, it doesn't provider the version for running in the browser. It is required to run under the cordova environment(`Android, iOS, Windows` platform) instead of browser.

Comment: Figured that the hard way. Thanks Fei. i really appreciate it

Comment: If the suggestion is helpful, you can accept is as answer so that other community who have the same issue could research and recolonize the issue more easily.

Comment: Thanks Fei Xue. Is it possible to contact you privately?

Comment: I suggest that you reopen a new thread if you have other issues. So that others who are familiar with the issue could share their experience. Also I will look into the issue to see whether I can provider any help.